# create table into tablecell using Recursion in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

create dynamic table into tablecell itself using recursion logic in asp.net

I want to create second table from first tablecell. I would like to use recursion logic using asp.net. I need to be parent table instead of having two child table using recursion logic. To ensure the details are having cell of parent table gets child table. I have to do one parent table and it has two child tables are inside of table cell like I would like to add the content inside of table cell. This content is like child table and ensure this accessing variables from outside. Here gets to one parent and it has two children using asp.net.

Comment: // Current row count. 
int rowCtr; 
int cellCtr; 
int cellCnt; 
rowCnt = int.Parse(TextBox1.Text); 
cellCnt = int.Parse(TextBox2.Text); 

for(rowCtr=1; rowCtr <= rowCnt; rowCtr++) { 
    TableRow tRow = new TableRow(); 
    Table1.Rows.Add(tRow); 

    for (cellCtr = 1; cellCtr <= cellCnt; cellCtr++) { 
        TableCell tCell = new TableCell(); 
        tCell.Text = "Row " + rowCtr + ", Cell " + cellCtr;
        tRow.Cells.Add(tCell); –

Comment: i want to create sub table into parent tablecell using recursion  logic in asp.net

Comment: I am trying create a table and add this table into tablecell(table inside table in short)

It seems to be working with asp.net table. I have tried to add other controls to the particular cell,

Comment: Hi @Siva Sankar, you can edit your question after posting. It's under the tags below your question body.